# Set status bar color via xml

Tags: java, android, xml

i want to set the `StatusBar` color using the API level of android `kitkat 4.4`. I want to set the color to the status bar without using external library (system bar tint>) and via xml. How can I do this?

for the moment my style in `values-v19` is

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>  
    </style>

</resources>
```